# python multiprocessing.Queue.put/get's block parameter

Tags: python

That is the Official Docs about multiprocessing.Queue.get

> get([block[, timeout]])
>
> Remove and return an item from the queue. If
>   optional args block is True (the default) and timeout is None (the
>   default), block if necessary until an item is `available`. If timeout
>   is a positive number, it blocks at most timeout seconds and raises the
>   Queue.Empty exception if no item was available within that time.
>   Otherwise (block is False), return an item if one is `immediately
>   available`, else raise the Queue.Empty exception (timeout is ignored
>   in that case).

The question is what is the difference between `available` and `immediately available`

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

> block if necessary until an item is available

This simply means `Queue` is empty when you make the request and it will be blocked until you add an item to the `Queue`, unless you pass the argument `block = False` or set some `Timeout`.

> immediately available

This means, there is some item on `Queue` when you make the request and it will be returned immediately.

Comment: I can get your idea, but the answer above is more clear, so I give the correct label to him.

Answer (score 1):

In the first case where `block=True` is set, `"available"` means when an item is present on the queue and ready to be removed by `Queue.get()`. The point is that the thread/process will block *until* there is an item ready to be removed from the queue.

In the second case, `block=False` so the calling thread will *not* block if there is no item in the queue (no item is `"immediately available"` on the queue). Instead `Queue.get()` will raise `Queue.Empty` to signify that there is nothing on the queue to read. Your application needs to handle that exception, possibly by performing other tasks and then trying again later.